# How to prevent embedded requests to my webpage?

Tags: security, web-applications, cookies, csrf

I have a webpage that tracks my users whenever they visit the page. It is a "profile page" whereby if someone visit your "profile page", his visit would be tracked and you would be notified.

This is similar to [stackoverflow's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632951/pacerier) which keeps track of *profile views* (although the details differ). Whenever a unique visitor visits your profile page, the profile views counter will be incremented.

I authenticate users using a randomly generated token stored in their browser's cookies. And this is where I have a big [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) problem because **any random website could simply visit the webpage on behalf of my users, without them knowing**. For example, an attacker's webpage could simply have an embedded iframe or image which points to my webpage:

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/profile-page">

or

<iframe src="http://mysite.com/profile-page"></iframe>
```

Whenever my users visit the attacker's webpage, they would be visiting someone's profile page without them knowing it (the visit is then logged).

**Let me use a concrete example to demonstrate my point:**

Many websites these days allows users to post image URLs. The user can post an image like this:

```
 <img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/632951/pacerier">
```

The `src` of the image tag really isn't an image file, but the browser will still make the request and display an empty image:

[image]

This means that the attacker had just successfully made a request to https://stackoverflow.com/users/632951/pacerier on the user's behalf, most likely without the user even knowing it.

As mentioned in [Preventing CSRF and XSRF Attacks](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html), we could add some hidden input fields and a form saying "Are you sure you want to request this page?". The disadvantage is that every genuine user that requests the page would now need to click the button <kbd>Yes, Confirm Request Page</kbd> before they can visit the webpage, which would severely break usability. **I don't want to force users to click** <kbd>Confirm</kbd> **for every page that does tracking.**

Are there other more user-friendly ways to prevent CSRF get requests?

How can we tell the browser not to request pages from a domain http://mysite.com if it is an *embedded* page (browser's url bar is not showing the requested page, which means it's an embedded image, frame, iframe, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way that ought to be fairly simple and reliable:

- Don't count the requests made *for* the page, but rather requests made by something *on* the page (e.g. AJAX requests, and/or requests for an image on the page).  This will take care of `img` hacks, since browsers won't actually try to render an HTML page as an image, and so won't run any JavaScript or load any (sub)images on the page.
- Add an [`X-Frame-Options: DENY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header to the page, so that browsers won't render it in an `iframe` either.  For older browsers (or just as part of a belt-and-suspenders approach), you can also have your JavaScript check that [`window.parent == window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent) before sending the AJAX confirmation.
- Finally, to protect the (AJAX / image) requests that you *do* count from spoofing, include a unique, unpredictable token that is valid only once in each of them.  One way to do that is to generate the tokens randomly and save them in a database (or in session storage) until they're received back (or get too old).

  Alternatively, if you don't want to store the tokens in a database, you could calculate a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) of a timestamp (and e.g. the user's IP address) and send both with the request, discounting any requests with a wrong MAC or a stale timestamp.

Comment: Regarding your third point, wouldn't that mean making URLs ugly?

Comment: Also, is there a X-Frame-Options: DENY equivalent for images?

Comment: Yes, the URLs _for the AJAX requests_ will be ugly (unless you use a POST request, in which case the ugly stuff will be in the request body), but the user will never see those, so who cares? And no, there's no `X-Frame-Options` for images, but there doesn't need to be: as long as you send a `text/html` (or `text/anything`) content type, browsers won't try to render your page as an image. They'll still have to _request_ it before they can find out what the content type is, but then, the same goes for `X-Frame-Options` too.

Comment: It's best to keep the URLs pretty... I don't use JavaScript / frames / iframes at all for my entire website. Or rather, it's only used as a "bonus" feature.

Comment: If you don't want to use JavaScript, you could also put a small image (essentially a local "web bug") on the page you want to track, and count requests to that image. The image URL will be ugly (since it needs to contain the token), but again, the user will never see it. Or you could combine both methods, wrapping the image in `<noscript>` tags and using the AJAX method where JS is available.